# Using chars.nth(i) in Rust removes the character from the String

Tags: rust

I was solving the Advent of Code 2022 - Day 2 with Rust for practice and I came across a strange issue/feature. The input format was multiple lines, each having two capital letters separated by a space.

```rust
  /* -- snip -- */
  for line in input.lines() { // separating the lines
    let mut chars = input.chars(); // get chars, such as ['A', ' ', 'X']
    let first_char = chars.nth(0).expect("Should have a character");
    let second_char = chars.nth(2).expect("Should have a 2nd character"); // <- PANIC!

    /* -- snip -- */
```

Upon executing this program, it kept panicking at the commented line. When I debugged it, I saw that when I was accessing `chars.nth(0)`, then that character is removed from `chars`. Hence, the third character in my list (i.e. at index 2) is now at index 1.

For this example, it was an easy brute-force fix. But I would imagine this would get confusing for programs with more complexity. Why does this happen in Rust? What is the correct way to index characters from a String without actually mutating it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) returns an iterator, and [`nth()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) is advancing this iterator. Once an iterator advances, it can never step back. From now on, all operations on this iterator will exclude the items we stepped over. It doesn't remove the items from the string, only from the iterator.

This is explicitly mentioned in `nth()`'s docs:

> Note that all preceding elements, as well as the returned element, will be consumed from the iterator. That means that the preceding elements will be discarded, and also that calling `nth(0)` multiple times on the same iterator will return different elements.

To start counting from zero, just use a fresh iterator (invocation of `chars()`) each time:

```rust
  /* -- snip -- */
  for line in input.lines() { // separating the lines
    let first_char = input.chars().nth(0).expect("Should have a character");
    let second_char = input.chars().nth(2).expect("Should have a 2nd character");

    /* -- snip -- */
```